# aldryn hello world issue

Tags: python, django, django-cms, divio

I'm teaching myself how to use Aldryn to host a django-cms website. I've been working though the application development tutorial on the [readthedocs](http://docs.aldryn.com/en/latest/tutorial/commandline/working-on-backend.html) site and I've gotten almost all the way to the end. When I run `aldryn project up` I get an error that tells me to check the logs. I check the logs using `docker-compose logs web` and at the end of the log I see: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: CMS Plugins must define a render template (<class 'hello_world_ct.cms_plugins.HelloWorld'>) that exists: hello_world_ct/hello.html`

For some reason the aldryn project doesn't seem to recognize the face that I have a render_template defined inside the `class HelloWorld(CMSPluginBase):`. When I comment out the render_template the log gives me the same error.

I've setup the project EXACTLY as the tutorial tells me to. The directory tree inside the addons-dev folder is like this:

```
hello-world-ct/
├── addon.json
├── hello_world_ct
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── cms_plugins.py
│   ├── cms_plugins.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── hello_world_ct
│   │       └── hello.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
└── setup.py
```

The cms_plugins.py file looks like:

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin

class HelloWorld(CMSPluginBase):
    model = CMSPlugin
    render_template = "hello_world_ct/hello.html"
    text_enabled = True

plugin_pool.register_plugin(HelloWorld)
```

... it looks right to me but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: It's worth double-checking, just to be certain, that your paths and references to paths really do both contain underscores, not dashes (`hello_world_ct`).

Comment: To debug you could try fetch the template through django manually, to see if it is a general problem with template loading or a specific problem in the Plugin. First comment out ``plugin_pool.register_plugin(HelloWorld)`` in ``cms_plugins.py``, so that django can start. Hop into the django shell with ``docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py shell``. Then ``from django.template import loader; loader.get_template("hello_world_ct/hello.html")``. Also try ``loader.get_template("base.html")`` (some template you know works) as a reference to test.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. Here's the solution that worked for me.

In the `settings.py` file, add the template folder of your app to `TEMPLATES` variable:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_core_app', 'core_app_templates_folder'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hello_world_ct', 'templates'),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
             ...
        },
    },
]
```

And add the template name to the `CMS_TEMPLATES` variable:

```py
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('fullwidth.html', 'Fullwidth'),
    ...
    ('hello.html', 'Hello World CT'),
```